# spelling out numbers in formal writing

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am writing a statement of purpose and wondering how to write "26" in my SOP. Do I have to spell it out "twenty-six" or can I write it as 26? I am confused by web searching.

Please help. Thanks..

Comment: This seems to be just a general writing question. See e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/q/979

Comment: I agree, this is a general writing question, I think the rule of thumb is to spell out numbers upto about 10, and beyond that write with numerals (though this isn't a hard rule and likely won't result in a significant difference in the outcome). Though in some places spelling out small numbers may be confusing, such as in a table of numbers.

Comment: Like @GoodDeeds has mentioned, it's not very specific to academia. I'd like to provide some reasons as to *why are general rules the way they are*. Numbers in text make the brain kind of stumble a bit, and it is the most evident when being bilingual - when reading an English text aloud from my screen to friends, I'd unconsciously replace numbers - written as numerals - with words in my native tongue. Now, sometimes this effect is desired, similar to how scientific notation gives yet another specific perception of numbers.

Comment: So say looking at a pinout diagram I'd probably prefer "the output has 10 pins" to make me "stumble" and give extra attention to this while "she is ten years old" does not "load a library for numerical computations into the brain" and allows for uninterrupted flow and more efficient use of "common sense" resources. For numbers larger than ten, numerical representation is more common, although spelling it out may still make sense if what you want the reader to focus on is some general idea and not a very specific number.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a common enough question from academics to answer.  The following are *not* inviolable rules, but they tend to work for most writing:

1. Usually, you spell out numbers smaller than 10 if they appear in a sentence and use the numerals otherwise.  For instance, "The cost is $10,523" rather than "The cost is Ten Thousand Five Hundred...".  This is to simplify and tighten the writing.
2. You use the numerals almost always for decimal numbers unless there is a very, very specific reason not to.  One such reason might be in a direct quote, where the precise wording is important, such as "Dr. Smith said `the number on the console is three oh one point two five'".  Here, perhaps we are focusing on the fact that the "oh" might be ambiguous and we wanted to quote every single word exactly as it was said.  Otherwise, use the numerals.
3. When two numbers appear right after the other, especially in the case of counting.  Example: "There were 12 fifty-mm bolts".  This reduces ambiguity and errors compared to "There were 12 50-mm bolts", as it helps the reader to understand that one is a count and one is a size.
4. Years are always referred to using numerals.  So it is 1955, not "nineteen fifty five" unless, again, you are doing a direct quote where the precise wording matters.
5. Avoid starting a sentence with a numeral.  So "Fifteen hundred cars were sold" is correct, not "1500 cars were sold".

That should cover most cases!